# Python3 Asyncio Queue - get queued in background?

Tags: python-3.x, queue, python-asyncio

Hi i have a problem with asyncio queues. I have a asyncio "server" with TCP connections and i'd like to do something like a queue cleaner.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(server, '127.0.0.1', 8888, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)



print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))

while True:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

and main() is

```
async def main():
    if queue.empty() == True:
        pass
    while queue.empty() != True:
        item = await queue.get()
        print(item)
        print("queue items: ")
        print(queue.qsize())
```

But i dont think that this is the best method to do tasks from queue. I want to make a second script which do only queue thinks. Is there any way to connect to my servers queue from outside and do things with that?

Now it looks like:
client -> server => receive task, and add it to queue -> make loop clean. It is not asynced, because logically i will never have more than 1 think in queue.

I want to:

client -> server => receive task <= clean tasks from outside

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If your `main()` is dequeueing items without processing them (thus effectively stealing them), why have the queue in the first place?

Comment: @user4815162342 so "get" doesn't mean that it processing that? this items are functions. hmm it make sense because now i made sleep in one of these function and program was not stopped. So can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: ok i edited that. sorry for ignorance. .

Comment: `get` means you've popped an item off the queue, and then it's your responsibility to process it! If printing the item is valid processing (e.g. for demonstration purposes), then yes, this is the correct way to do it.

Also, you don't need to check for `queue.empty()` - the whole point of awaiting `queue.get()` is that it waits as long as needed for the queue to become non-empty.

Comment: @user4815162342 im not sure if im doing it right now. I have response " consuming item <coroutine object order.sell_order at 0x108e9edc8>...
" i used this stuff https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/producer_consumer.html 

Function i want to put in queue making some calculations and will put (in future) it in database. im using that:
item = o.new_order(A,P) 
await queue.put(item)
then im using it like:

        item = await queue.get()
        if item is None:
            break

        # process the item
        print('consuming item {}...'.format(item))

Comment: If the item you retrieved from the queue is a "coroutine object", it sounds like you are missing an `await` on the producer side. It's hard to say more without a minimal example that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: @user4815162342 now i have response consuming item {'orders_value': 2, 'not_finished_orders': True}. Its return from my function. Does it mean that function is done correctly? Sorry but i have storm in my head, because of this stuff.

Comment: You should know what you want to put in the queue, I'm afraid I cannot answer that for you. Do you understand what purpose a queue actually serves?

Comment: @user4815162342 thank you for your time. i read yesterday more docs of queues and now im understand. Thank you very much for help !

Comment: No problem! If your problem is resolved, please remember to answer or delete the question. If there are parts you still don't understand, feel free to edit the question.